# SQlite admin for android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm the author of [SQLiteManager](http://www.sqlitemanager.org) And i want to code same application for android.
In your opinion, what language should I use?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

That's easy ;)

Java, since it is the only option.

(Well, there is the possibility to use the Android NDK, but Java should still be you tool of choice).

And you should keep in mind, that you don't have permission to access databases from other applications, since on android every app lives in it's own sandbox. Sharing data on an android device is done via Content Providers http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html